# Custom VB code not working in power bi paginated report

Tags: vb.net, powerbi

I have created following code to resize image in vb. below code working fine in visual studio but when i am including this code in power bi report builder's custom code function, then its not working.

```
Public Function CropImages(ByRef ImageURL As String) As Byte()
        Dim req As System.Net.WebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(ImageURL.Trim)
        Dim OriginalImage As System.Drawing.Bitmap
        Using request As System.Net.WebResponse = req.GetResponse
            Using stream As System.IO.Stream = request.GetResponseStream
                OriginalImage = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream))
            End Using
        End Using
        'Dim Client As New WebClient
        'Dim OriginalImage As Bitmap = Bitmap.FromStream(New MemoryStream(Client.DownloadData(ImageURL)))
        Dim CropImage = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(OriginalImage, New System.Drawing.Size(351, 197))
        Dim ms = New System.IO.MemoryStream()
        CropImage.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
        Dim bytes = ms.ToArray()
        Return bytes

    End Function
```

getting below output

[image]